# Computer freezes when running compilation

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cpu-usage, ram, swapfile

OS: Ubuntu 14.04, 4GB ram, i5, 1.5 GB swap space
I'm running a compilation command `./build.sh` , however, the computer keeps on freezing during running it. I checked the RAM, CPU and Swap Space usage during the compilation and all of them are completely used. What will be the best solution to tackle this? I tried increasing swap space using swap file, however, the max limit (for swap file) seems to be 3 GB which is also being used completely.

Answer (score 0):

Can I know the command you are using, anyways if you are using make like this:

> make -j4 -l4

change it to:

> make -j2 -l2

Also, I think the swap space is too low, it should be at least equal to RAM. If the problem is not solved by above command, follow this [tutorial](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-create-or-increase-swap-space-in-linux) to increase swap space.

Comment: I'm running 
`./bulid.sh`
How do I make the mentioned changes?

Comment: Can you add build.sh to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by increase RAM to 8 GB as well as by increasing the SWAP space to 5 GB. When the compilation is run it was observed that the maximum 5.5 GB of RAM was used, so both RAM and Swap space were not sufficient.